# How to remove whitespace from an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document from which I want to remove white spaces and carriage returns. How can I get the modified XML using C#.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the preserveWhitespace flag to false:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
doc.Load("foo.xml");
// doc.InnerXml contains no spaces or returns
```

Comment: AareP is correct, doesnt work when using doc.LoadXml(...) directlt after.

Comment: Note that if the document contains any `xml:space="preserve"` attributes, it will not work (by design of course), so one has to remove these attributes before loading.

Comment: another answer, using [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-6.0) (from System.Xml.Linq), can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111760/724039

Answer (score 7):

To remove white spaces between the tags:

```
# Regex regex = new Regex(@">\s*<");  
# string cleanedXml = regex.Replace(dirtyXml, "><");
```

Source and other usefull info [here](http://neilkilbride.blogspot.com/2008/04/removing-xmldocument-white-space-c.html)

Comment: wouldn't it remove also whitespace from CDATA sections? in other words in places where this should be intact?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this just using a more complete regex:

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"[\s]+(?![^><]*(?:>|<\/))");
var cleanedXml = regex.Replace(xml, "");
```

This regex will remove all the spaces between closed tags.

Input example:

```xml
<root>
   <result success="1"/>
   <userID>12345</userID>
   <classID>  56543  </classID>
</root>
```

Output for the input:

```xml
<root><result success="1"/><userID>12345</userID><classID>  56543  </classID>
</root>
```

A more complete explanation of this regex can be found on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771445/6846888