# how to remove carriage returns, newlines, spaces from a string

Tags: c#, xml, regex, string

How do I remove the spaces, carriage returns from in between `<` and `>` ?

```
**START BELOW THIS LINE***

<TestItem1Request>
  <Username>admin</Username>
  <Password>123abc..@!</Password>
  <Item1>this is an item</Item1>
</TestItem1Request>

**END HERE **
```

I want the string result to end up as the following...

```
</TestItem1Request><Username>admin</Username><Password>123abc..@!</Password><Item1>this is an item</Item1></TestItem1Request>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your resulting string has spaces in between <Item1>  I think you are approaching your problem wrong, but if you have a string you can just do a string newstring = oldstring.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n","");

Comment: Is that supposed to be well-formed XML?

Comment: No, iterationx.  If it is well-formed XML, your solution could modify the legitimate string values.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231374/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-an-xmldocument

Comment: Thanks lnuyasha, this is the correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231374/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-an-xmldocument

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If this is valid XML you could use the [SaveOptions.DisableFormatting enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx):

```
string input = @"<TestItem1Request>
  <Username>admin</Username>
  <Password>123abc..@!</Password>
  <Item1>this is an item</Item1>
</TestItem1Request>";

string result = XElement.Parse(input).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```