# Convert node section into one line

Tags: c#, xml

i have xml document with a **lot of items** like this:

```
 <item>
    <key>
       <unsignedShort>x</unsignedShort>
    </key>
    <value>
       <unsignedShort>y</unsignedShort>
    </value>
 </item>


 <item>
......
```

now i want that every section of it will look like this:

```
<item><key><unsignedShort>x</unsignedShort></key><value><unsignedShort>y</unsignedShort></value></item>
```

Comment: Duplicate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111712/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-newlines-spaces-from-a-string).

Comment: but i want that every item will be under the pervious item:
<item><key>
..
<item><key>
i need to detect where item is begin and when it's ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement your own XmlWriter. [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting.aspx) allows you to use an unindented format, but that would result in the entire document being on one line. So, yeah, you'd have to roll your own, unless you're OK with the entire document sitting on one line.