# How to remove whitespace between tags of pseudo-XML

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have some pseudo/ill-formed XML for which I need to remove the whitespace between tags.  Leveraging a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111712/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-newlines-spaces-from-a-string), if I have the following content:

```
  <Username>admin</Username>
  <Password>123abc..@!</Password>
  <Item1>this is an item</Item1>
```

... how do I get the following output?

```
<Username>admin</Username><Password>123abc..@!</Password><Item1>this is an item</Item1>
```

Below is what I've tried:

```
internal static class StringExtensions
{
    internal static string SquashXml(this string input)
    {
        var squashed = Regex.Replace(input, @"\<[\S\s]+\>([\r\n\t]+)", String.Empty);
        return squashed;
    }
}
```

There's something wrong with the Regex (I think), but I can't pinpoint it.  This is the output I get:

```
<Item1>this is an item</Item1>
```

Comment: `[\S\s]` is interesting. Isn't that the same thing as `.`?

Comment: Yes it is.  I forgot my disclaimer that I'm no wiz with Regex.

Comment: The link you posted is how you _should_ look into doing it - essentially treating it as a "document", vs some "free text". [Beware regex for documents (xml, html, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/304683)

Comment: I see.  I didn't know that Regex has basic challenges working with XML (assuming that's what I've got when there's no nesting).  I'll revisit this to see if I can get an XML parser to work with this.

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for parsing XML. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: To be honest, I only asked the question to see if anybody else would go insane.