# Render Razor View as string resulted in extra formatting tags (tabs, line-breaks)? How to remove?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've asked this question as a comment on another post but couldn't get it to work. I'm using [RenderRazorViewToString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/248480), but somehow the JSON that get returned got all the Visual studio formatting with it (tabs, white spaces, line-breaks, etc...), here's what I've done:

```
public virtual ActionResult RenderToString()
{
    var html = RenderRazorViewToString(MVC.Markets.Views._RenderToString);
    return Json(new { html = html }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here's the result that got returned:

```
{"html": "<div class=\"frame company-quote contain\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceModule\">\r\n\t<div data-module-name=\"CompanyHeaderModule\">\r\n\t\t<h1>\r\n\t\t\tMicrosoft Corp <em>(MSFT:NASDAQ)</em></h1>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<div class=\"first-glance\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceQuoteModule\">\r\n\t\t<table>\r\n\t\t\t<thead>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tPrice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tChange\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tVolume\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tMarket Cap\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t\t</thead>\r\n\t\t\t<tbody>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$30.13\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"neg\">-0.13</span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t32.75 M\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$252.77 B\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t\t</tbody>\r\n\t\t</table>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<div class=\"controls\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceControlsModule\">\r\n\t\t<em>Data as of February 15, 2012 01:59:59 PM ET</em>\r\n\t\t<div>\r\n\t\t\t<button class=\"type-1\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span>Add to Watchlist</span></button>\r\n\t\t\t<button class=\"type-2\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span>Trade</span></button>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>\r\n"}
```

I've tried to add an extension method [outlined here](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/9/9/formatting-xml-in-c.html) to reformat this into xml with Formatting.None and got a slightly better result, but still have extra tags as well as the xml version tag which I probably don't want:

```
{"html": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><div class=\"frame company-quote contain\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceModule\"><div data-module-name=\"CompanyHeaderModule\"><h1>\r\n\t\t\tMicrosoft Corp <em>(MSFT:NASDAQ)</em></h1></div><div class=\"first-glance\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceQuoteModule\"><table><thead><tr><th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tPrice\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th><th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tChange\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th><th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tVolume\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th><th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tMarket Cap\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$30.13\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td><td><span class=\"neg\">-0.13</span></td><td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t32.75 M\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td><td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$252.77 B\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class=\"controls\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceControlsModule\"><em>Data as of February 15, 2012 01:59:59 PM ET</em><div><button class=\"type-1\"><span>Add to Watchlist</span></button><button class=\"type-2\"><span>Trade</span></button></div></div></div>"}
```

Any idea on how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing with the result that makes it matter that the whitespace comes with it?

Comment: Actually, whatever the reason, it should be trivial to use string.Replace or a similar method to strip out all the tabs, newlines, and carriage returns.

Comment: The amount of data bandwidth, etc... Also, I'm not sure if using string.Replace() will slow down it even more with all the string manipulation going on behind the scene.

Comment: Yes, but that's how the framework renders the view.  Unless you want to write your own code to do that, you're probably stuck doing string manipulation on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399798/memory-efficiency-and-performance-of-string-replace-net-framework), it looks like there are issues with string.Replace and large strings, since they're immutable, but StringBuilder should work well even on large strings.

```
public virtual ActionResult RenderToString()
{
    string html = RenderRazorViewToString(MVC.Markets.Views._RenderToString);
    html = new StringBuilder(html)
        .Replace("\n","")
        .Replace("\r","")
        .Replace("\t","")
        .ToString();
    return Json(new { html = html }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Add any other whitespace characters as needed.

Answer (score 1):

As the view should be returning valid XML, you could try and use something like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult RenderToString()
{
    var html = RenderRazorViewToString(MVC.Markets.Views._RenderToString);
    string clean = XElement.Parse(html).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
    return Json(new { html = clean }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or there is another neat option [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231374/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-an-xmldocument)

Comment: Hi @Tr1stan, this helps a little, but there are still a lot of "\r\n\t"..., i.e:      {"html":"<div class=\"frame company-quote contain\" data-module-name=\"FirstGlanceModule\"><div data-module-name=\"CompanyHeaderModule\"><h1>\r\n\t\t\tMicrosoft Corp <em>(MSFT:NASDAQ)</em></h1>