# How do I remove all excess whitespace from an XML string using ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I receive an XML string from a client in a format like the following...

```
<root>
   <result success="1"/>
   <userID>12345</userID>
   <classID>56543</classID>
</root>
```

I need to compress this string down to the following...

```
<root><result success="1"/><userID>12345</userID><classID>56543</classID></root>
```

So, all of the whitespace is removed, except inside of the tag (so the space still exists between "result" and "success").

I have used `replace` statements to remove line breaks, carriage returns, etc, but I can't remove spaces while ignoring the spaces inside tags. Is there a way to use a regular expression or some other method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below regx would match the spaces which are not within the tags,

```
[\s]+(?![^><]*>)
```

OR

```
[\s]+(?![^><]*(?:>|<\/))
```

Just replace the matched spaces with an empty string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rO9iN0/2)

**Edit Starts Here**

From the comments - in the context of ColdFusion it works like this...

```
strClean = REReplace(strOriginal,"[\s]+(?![^><]*(?:>|<\/))","","All");
```

Comment: If anyone is interested, in the context of ColdFusion it works like this...

strClean = REReplace(strOriginal,"[\s]+(?![^><]*(?:>|<\/))","","All");

Comment: I tested those regexps in JavaScript and they don't work properly. `[\s]+(?![^><]*>)` cuts whitespaces where it shouldn't (from inside of a text). On the other hand `[\s]+(?![^><]*(?:>|<\/))` miss some whitespaces.

Comment: If you have anchor tag in your text It will remove whitespaces between the <a> tag and the opening parent tag.

Answer (score 2):

How about the simple Regex: `>\s+?<` and replace with `><`. As a bonus over the accepted answer, this will keep the whitespace in leaf/terminal elements.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the exact result i wanted using any Regex approach and I have a hunch that treating XML with Regex is not really comme il faut. For XML, I like to stay in the XML realm and you can accomplish what you want using XmlTransform.

Using this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can simply do this:

```
xmlOut = XmlTransform(xmlIn, stripSpaceXSL);
```

See Demo: https://trycf.com/gist/d6be6b6b8e04ccea3dbd9ece9c60fa2c/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, working solution I see is to replace all whitespaces near outer side of angle brackets:

- `>\s+` by `>`, and
- `\s+<` by `<`.

In ColdFusion it should be something like:

```
str = REReplace(str, ">\s+", ">", "All");
str = REReplace(str, "\s+<", "<", "All");
```